# DPDK l2fwd - How to forward ethernet interface to my PMD

Tags: dpdk, dpdk-pmd

I have a board with one ethernet interface (eth0) running Linux.
I'm trying to forward all incoming traffic from eth0 to my PMD driver, using dpdk-l2fwd example application.

Here is what I've tried:

```
./dpdk-l2fwd -c 0x3 --vdev={my_pmd}0 -- -p 0x3 -T 0
```

I can see that my **rx_pkt_burst** callback is polled by the application, but that's it.

How can I forward all incoming eth0 packets to my PMD?

I tried to use net_tap, using the following command:

```
./dpdk-l2fwd -c 0xff --vdev=net_tap0 --vdev={my_pmd}0 -- -p 0x7 -T 0 --portmap="(1,2)"
```

And my **tx_pkt_burst** callback is called occasionally, but not when I think it should be called.
For example, if I ping this board from another one, the ping is successful, but the **tx_pkt_burst** callback is not been called.

I tried to use devbind tool, but no devices are detected:

```
./usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --status

No 'Network' devices detected
=============================

No 'Baseband' devices detected
==============================

No 'Crypto' devices detected
============================

No 'Eventdev' devices detected
==============================

No 'Mempool' devices detected
=============================

No 'Compress' devices detected
==============================

No 'Misc (rawdev)' devices detected
===================================

No 'Regex' devices detected
===========================
```

**Update**

- DPDK version - 20.11.
- My HW is a embedded device based on NXP's Layerscape.

```
$ lshw -class network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 00:11:22:44:11:44
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt-fd 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=fsl_dpaa2_eth driverversion=5.10.35-00002-g3434eea0e1e7-dir duplex=full firmware=7.17 ip=192.168.15.157 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
```

I'm trying to bypass all traffic to the PMD I'm currently developing.

Thanks.

Comment: there are couple of things which you need to correct, like 1. since you mention that you are interested in 1 port, then your port mask should be `-p 0x1 and not -p 0x3`, 2. There are couple of ways to get traffic from your port like `1. xdp PMD or 2. PCAP PMD`. But these factors depends upon on your type of NIC (eth0). So please update your question with DPDK version, type of NIC, and whether or not you intent to bypass all traffic to DPDK or not to help you with the answer.

Comment: updated the answer, please read and check the settings as descried. happy to make myself available for a live debug. Let me know

Comment: thanks for the update, let me know a good time to sync with you on the new request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT-1] clarification of using same interface for DPDK and Kernel routing

Answer> as discussed over comments please refer to [DPDKD + kernel on same interface](https://superuser.com/questions/1565392/how-to-setup-dpdk-without-loosing-ssh-connection/1565862#1565862)

Based on the information shared there are multiple questions to the single query `I'm trying to bypass all traffic to the PMD I'm currently developing`. Addressing each one separately below

1. question 1: **using dpdk-l2fwd example application**

Answer> DPDK application [l2fwd](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/l2_forward_real_virtual.html) application makes use of basic APi with almost no HW offloads. Based on your environment (I have a board with one ethernet interface (eth0)), the right set of parameters should be `-p 0x1 --no-mac-updating -T 1`. This will configure the application to receive and transmit packet using single DPDK interface (that is eth0 on your board).

Note: DPDK Application can work with DPDK PMD both physical and virtual

2. question 2: **I tried to use net_tap, using the following command:**

Answer> If the intend is to intercept the traffic from physical and then forward to tap interface, then one needs modify the eal arguments as `./build/l2fwd --vdev=net_tap0,iface="my_eth0" -- -p 0x3 -T 1 --no-mac-updating`. This will allow the application to probe physical NXP interface (eth0) and make use of Linux TAP interface as secondary interface. Thus any traffic from NXP and TAP will be cross connected such as `NXP (eth0) <==> TAP (my_eth0)`

3. question 3: ***./usertools/dpdk-devbind.py** --status returns empty*

Answer> Form the dpdk site [supported NIC](http://core.dpdk.org/supported/) list NXP `dpaa, dpaa2, enetc, enetfec, pfe`. Cross checking the kernel driver `fsl_dpaa2_eth`  I think it is safe to assume  dpaa2 PMD is supported. As you have mentioned the NIC is not enumerated, it looks like there are certain caveats to such model revision, supported board, BSP package, vendor-sub vendor ID check etc. More details can be found [Board Support Package](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/platform/dpaa2.html), and [DPAA2 NIC guide](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/dpaa2.html)

Debug & Alternative solutions:

1. To start with use the Kernel Driver to bring in packets
2. Use extra logging and debug to identify why the NIC is shown in the application

***Approach 1:***

3. Make sure the NIC is bind with kernel driver `fsl_dpaa2_eth`.
4. ensure NIC is connected and link is up with `ethtool eth0`
5. set to promiscous mode with `ifconfig eth0 promisc up`
6. start DPDK application with PCAP PMD, `./build/l2fwd --vdev=net_pcap0,iface=eth0 -- -p 1 --no-mac-updating -T 1`
7. Check packet are received and redirected to PCAP eth0 PMD by checking the statistics.

***Approach 2:***

1. Ideally the NIC should be categorized under network device to be probed by debind.py.
2. Check the device details using `lshw -c net -businfo` for `network`.
3. try checking with `lspci -Dvmmnnk [PCIe BUS:Slot:Function id]` for network details.
4. If above details does not show up as network device this might be reason for not getting listed.

- Suggestions or workaround: You can try to forcefully bind with igb_uio or vfio-pci (I am not much famialr with NXP SoC) by `dpdk-devbind -b vfio-pci [PCIe S:B:F]`. Then cross check with `lspci -ks [PCIe S:B:F]`. Once successfully done, one can start dpdk l2fwd in PMD debug mode with `./build/l2fwd -a [PCIe S:B:F] --log-level=pmd,8 -- -p 1 --no-mac-updating | more`. Thus by intercepting and interpreting the logs one can identify what is going

Note:

1. It is assumed the application is build with static libraries and not dynamic. To build with static libraries use `make static` for l2fwd.
2. For the described use case recommended application is `basicfwd/skeleton` rather than l2fwd.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I think that I may have over complicated it. All I need to do is forward all eth0 traffic to my PMD (the one I'm currently developing), so I thought that I may need to forward eth0 traffic to my PMD using l2fwd `eth0 <==> MY PMD`. I was able to forward tap0 traffic to my  PMD using: `./dpdk-l2fwd  --vdev=net_tap0 --vdev={my_pmd}0 -- -p 0x7 -T 0 --portmap="(1,2)"` 
`MY PMD <==> TAP`, I need to do the same with the physical eth0 port. So when I will ping this board, my PMD will receive the ping packets. How can I achieve it?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Alvaro thanks for the update and confirming the understanding. You can accept and upvote to close this thread. With respect to the new question, I think it will easy to sync up via a live debug as I had already shared an `option with XDP in comment`. Will wait for your invite.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently adding XDP support to my kernel.                                    I'm not sure what do you mean by "live debug", I could not find this option in stack overflow.                                                                                          XDP is the only option? There are no other options to  to forward eth0 traffic to my PMD?

Comment: Please refere https://superuser.com/questions/1565392/how-to-setup-dpdk-without-loosing-ssh-connection/1565862#1565862 for the new query. Live debug is with skype or google meet

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do a live debug.                                    I can't create a net_af_xdp device:                                         `./dpdk-l2fwd -c 0x3 --vdev=net_af_xdp,iface=eth0 --  -p 0x1 -T 1`                                  Output:
`EAL: Detected 16 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: failed to parse device "net_af_xdp"
EAL: Unable to parse device 'net_af_xdp,iface=eth0'
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Invalid EAL arguments`

Comment: @Alvaro thanks for the update, as suggested you can solve your new problem using AF_XDP pmd. Since you can not do a live debug, we can communicate via new question in this platform only.

Comment: ` EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK EAL: failed to parse device "net_af_xdp" EAL: Unable to parse device 'net_af_xdp,iface=eth0' EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1   Cause: Invalid EAL arguments` please open a new question for help

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
I had to unbind eth0 from Linux kernel.
Now I can simply run:

```
./dpdk-l2fwd -c 0x3 --vdev={MY_PMD}0 -- -p 0x3 -T 1
```

And all traffic in the physical port is forwarded to my PMD.